# What is the Math Notation for composing $n$ functions?

Tags: notation

Suppose I have $n$ functions namely $f_1,...,f_n$. If I want to sum them then I could use Sigma $\Sigma$, if I want to multiply them, I could use capital Pi $\Pi$. But what if I want to compose all of them? Is there a known notation convention for something like this:
$$\circ{}_{i=1}^n f_i$$

Comment: Sincw composition isn't conmutative, I'd just use $f_1\circ \ldots\circ f_n $ to avoid potential confusion.

Comment: I don't think there is an established notation for this. In particular, you'd have to disambiguate whether you mean $f_1\circ \ldots\circ f_n$ or $f_n\circ \ldots\circ f_1$